# Creating auto layouts for iphone se?

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I'm making an app that I want applicable to all sizes but the problem is that iPhone 8 up to iPad devices are good but I noticed that the iPhone SE and below iPhones are not being supported when you make your app for iPhone 8 and up because it's so small. Now does that mean I have to create a scroll view for all my pages not since it doesn't fit for iPhone SE and below or is it recommended to not just include iphone se size and below for any future app?

Comment: This can only done programmatically i believe

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to create your app to be universal and support all screen sizes to hit users from the market as much as you can , regrading support for IPhone 4 , 5 I think you need to have a scrollView in any screen that you think it may exceed screen height for these 2 devices ,  or create items height in proportional to screen height to guarantee that all UI elements will fit in the screen

Comment: Yeah. Most of the apps I create now use a scroll view by default. That way you get small screen support much more easily. :-) of course... if you use a table view or collection view then the scrolling comes for free so don’t also put that into a scroll view. :-)

Comment: @Fogmeister yes we have to as it will be embarrassing if the layout is trimmed , sure table and collection will help if the content of the layout is suitable for them

Comment: @Fogmeister So all your pages have a scroll view? because just in my login screen everything don't fit just because of the difference in the height for iphone se. Collection views usually adjust well to any phone sizes in my experience but other pages not so much lol.

Comment: @Jovin most. Not all. If it obviously isn’t going to cause a problem then I’ll go without. :-)